# Searcher of another value in a Range VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am designing a Pre sequencing VBA code that must seek the value introduced in a row (In this case the row Z starting in Z4 and ending in Z15) and must verify if it already exists in another row (in this case the row AB starting in AB4 and ending in AB15). If it does not exist it must place the time in the cell corresponding cell of the row AB (e.g. Z4 --> AB4, Z5 --> AB5). This is a way in which I assure that no AB cell contains a value equal to another AB value (understand the AB values as places in a row with two minutes of difference). If it finds the value of the Z row in the AB row, it must add two minutes to the Z value and check again if that "place" is already taken, until it founds a free place.

In the code below you can see a repititive statement for each Z in the row and at the end the function called each one of the statements.

THIS CODE DOES WORK, BUT, sometimes it has flaws, I dunno why, when the times are not introduced sequenctially from top to bottom it brings the error "Run-time error 457:This key is already associated with an element of this collection." and it does underline the statement "Dict.Add Hora, 1" at the function in the end of the code, it is like somehow a certain order introducing the data triggers the error. I proceed to insert an image for more clarification.
[Tool ilustration Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTlcN.png)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim HoraStr As String
Dim HorasOcupadas As Object: Set HorasOcupadas = CargaHorasOcupadas
Dim HoraDeseada As Date
Dim HoraOcupada As Boolean: HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Dim lrow4: lrow4 = Range("Z4").Row
Dim lrow5: lrow5 = Range("Z5").Row
Dim lrow6: lrow6 = Range("Z6").Row
Dim lrow7: lrow7 = Range("Z7").Row
Dim lrow8: lrow8 = Range("Z8").Row
Dim lrow9: lrow9 = Range("Z9").Row
Dim lrow10: lrow10 = Range("Z10").Row
Dim lrow11: lrow11 = Range("Z11").Row
Dim lrow12: lrow12 = Range("Z12").Row
Dim lrow13: lrow13 = Range("Z13").Row
Dim lrow14: lrow14 = Range("Z14").Row
Dim lrow15: lrow15 = Range("Z15").Row
If Target.Address = "$Z$4" Then
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C9")
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z4").Copy
Sheets("Tips").Range("K3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
HoraDeseada = Range("Z4").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
Do While HoraOcupada
    HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    .Cells(lrow4, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$5" Then
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z5").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C10")
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z5").Copy
Sheets("Tips").Range("K4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
HoraDeseada = Range("Z5").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
Do While HoraOcupada
    HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    .Cells(lrow5, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$6" Then
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z6").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C11")
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z6").Copy
Sheets("Tips").Range("K5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
HoraDeseada = Range("Z6").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
Do While HoraOcupada
    HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$7" Then
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z7").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C12")
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z7").Copy
Sheets("Tips").Range("K6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
HoraDeseada = Range("Z7").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
Do While HoraOcupada
    HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$8" Then
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z8").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C13")
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z8").Copy
Sheets("Tips").Range("K7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
HoraDeseada = Range("Z8").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
Do While HoraOcupada
    HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$9" Then
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z9").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C14")
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z9").Copy
Sheets("Tips").Range("K8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
HoraDeseada = Range("Z9").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
Do While HoraOcupada
    HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$10" Then
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C15")
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z10").Copy
Sheets("Tips").Range("K9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
HoraDeseada = Range("Z10").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
Do While HoraOcupada
    HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$11" Then
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z11").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C16")
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z11").Copy
Sheets("Tips").Range("K10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
HoraDeseada = Range("Z11").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
Do While HoraOcupada
    HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$12" Then
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z12").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C17")
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z12").Copy
Sheets("Tips").Range("K11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
HoraDeseada = Range("Z12").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
Do While HoraOcupada
    HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$13" Then
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C18")
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z13").Copy
Sheets("Tips").Range("K12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
HoraDeseada = Range("Z13").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
Do While HoraOcupada
    HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$14" Then
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z14").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C19")
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z14").Copy
Sheets("Tips").Range("K13").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
HoraDeseada = Range("Z14").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
Do While HoraOcupada
    HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$15" Then
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z15").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C20")
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z15").Copy
Sheets("Tips").Range("K14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
HoraDeseada = Range("Z15").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
Do While HoraOcupada
    HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Function CargaHorasOcupadas() As Object
Dim Dict As Object: Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    Dim lrow As Long: lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
    If lrow > 3 Then
        Dim C As Range
        Dim Hora As String
        For Each C In .Range("AB4:AB" & lrow)
            Hora = Format(C, "hh:mm")
            Dict.Add Hora, 1
        Next C
    End If
End With
Set CargaHorasOcupadas = Dict

End Function
```

Comment: the error you're facing thrown by `Dict.Add Hora, 1` tells you that  `Range("AB4:AB" & lrow)` in `Sheets("Hoja1")` has some duplicates. Maybe switching to "hh:mm.ss" format could prevent it. In any case you could change `Dict.Add Hora, 1` to `If Dict.Exists(Hora) Then -  MsgBox Hora & "duplicated in " & C.Address - Else -   Dict.Add Hora, 1 - End If` (where the hyphens stand for a new code line) and catch the possible duplicate when it actually is in place

Comment: I tried changing the format but it didn't work. But, the correction you offered catches the dupplicate, and brings the pop up stablished. The problem is, I do not need the pop up, I need it to add two minutes if that happens and check again, I tried with dateadd("n",2;"Hora") and the same mistake keeps appearing

Comment: Where did you put `dateadd("n",2;"Hora")`? What error is being thrown and at which line?

Comment: No error is thrown at all, but the time is not added, it shows the same value repetead in a cell before or after. I placed like this `If Dict.Exists(Hora) Then - Hora = DateAdd("n", 2, Hora) - Else - Dict.Add Hora, 1 - End If`

Comment: try the code as per my answer

Comment: I tried before, it brings the Message Box stablished, but it does not add two minutes to the time, it just notifies me that is duplicated.

Comment: I'm talking about my answer, not my comment!

Answer (score 0):

as per your last comment you could try and change the `For Each C` loop in `Function CargaHorasOcupadas()` as follows
:

```
        For Each C In .Range("AB4:AB" & lrow)
            Hora = Format(C, "hh:mm")
            Do While Dict.Exists(Hora)' if 'Hora' already in dictionary
                Hora = DateAdd("n", 2, Hora)' update 'Hora' by adding two minutes
            Loop' go to initial check 
            Dict.Add Hora, 1'once here you shoudl have a brand new 'Hora with no duplicates in Dict 
        Next C
```

but I'd suggest you to:

- make a backup copy of your files
- test the code by stepping through it:

  - put a breakpoint (F9) at line `Do While Dict.Exists(Hora)`
  - once the code reaches that line, use immediate window (CTRL-G to pop it out) and type `?Hora, Dict.Exists(Hora)` and press enter to see the outcome
  - if you are satisfied by the outcome, press F8 to step to next executable statament
  - and so on

Comment: It actually debugs the problem, but the outcome is not the correct, it does not add the 2 minutes, it gives back the time introduced... I do not know why

Comment: have you tested it as per my suggestions? (see my answer after the text _"test the code by stepping through it:"_)

Comment: Have you actually used the code in my answer? Your last comment below your question isn't using it…

Comment: Yeah, I did it, step by step, the outcome is the time introduced, before and after running the 'Do While' and I think now that the problem is the lrow definition, let me explain. I think that by defining several lrow, the function is not working properly. Nevertheless I tried with your modification just with one lrow definition for every cell, and in that case the mistake ‘Run-time error ‘13’: Type mismatch’ popped up, stressing the '                Hora = DateAdd("n", 2, Hora) ' update 'Hora' by adding two minutes' line

Comment: is this running now?